# Member reference base type is not a structure or union

Tags: c++, sfml

I need your help on one of my C++ project. 
I've got a semantic issue there :

```
Image bwImage(Image);
bwImage.setPixel(i,j,Color::Color( image.getPixel(i,j).r * RED + image.getPixel(i,j).g*GREEN + image.getPixel(i,j).b*BLUE,
image.getPixel(i,j).r*RED + image.getPixel(i,j).g*GREEN + image.getPixel(i,j).b*BLUE,
image.getPixel(i,j).r*RED + image.getPixel(i,j).g*GREEN + image.getPixel(i,j).b*BLUE) );
```

The error message is:

> "Member reference base type `sf::Image(sf::Image)` is not a structure
>   or union".

Does anyone know where is the problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: It looks like it is a function pointer - this `Image bwImage(Image);` would appear to declare a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is case sensitive. `Image` is the class name, while `image` is your object that instanciate the class.

From this [Documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Image.php#aa38cae7c1c704aa0175b9e73645cb210), `sf::Image` has a copy constructor:

```
sf::Image::Image    (   const Image &   Copy    )
```

You can build the `bwImage`, using that copy constructor, passing a reference to your `image` object.

So first line:

```
Image bwImage(Image);
```

Should be:

```
Image bwImage(image);
```

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Edited, Thanks

Comment: What about the other differences?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I'm not sure what you mean, can you be more specific?

Comment: @Mickael You are welcome. Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green)

Comment: `Image bwImage(Image);` declares a function. `Image bwImage(image);` defines a variable.